# Easy comparing MySQL plans in Django

Tags: django, sql-execution-plan

is there a way to print out query for example from this line of code

```
Model.objects.all().order_by(sort_headers.get_order_by())
```

I want to plan best way of using Django but with > 1 million of objects in my model this is getting too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Two options come to mind:

1. You can view the raw SQL queries as
   described in the [Django FAQ](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running):

   Make sure your Django DEBUG setting
   is set to True. Then, just do this:

   ```
   >>> from django.db import connection
   >>> connection.queries
   [{'sql': 'SELECT polls_polls.id,polls_polls.question,polls_polls.pub_date FROM polls_polls', 'time': '0.002'}]
   ```
2. You could also look at the
   `debugsqlshell` supplied as part of
   the [Django Debug Toolbar](http://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar)
   package. This outputs the underlying
   SQL for each ORM call that results
   in a database query, for example:

   ```
   >>> from page.models import Page
   >>> ### Lookup and use resulting in an extra query...
   >>> p = Page.objects.get(pk=1)
   SELECT "page_page"."id",
          "page_page"."number",
          "page_page"."template_id",
          "page_page"."description" FROM "page_page" WHERE
   "page_page"."id" = 1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Each queryset has a `.query` reference to the query object.  Printing this object will give you the query executed.

```
>>> f = Model.objects.all().order_by(sort_headers.get_order_by())
>>> print(f.query)
>>> query = str(f.query) # if you want to save it
```